# Bluemix Maximum number of spaces

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to organize Bluemix organizations and spaces for a multi-project environment. Is there any limit on the maximum number of spaces that one can create under one single Bluemix organization?

Comment: I would say you first run out of services, then spaces... I haven't seen any documented limit in both Cloud Foundry and Bluemix.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard-and-fast limit to the maximum number of spaces. Rather, the maximum number of spaces would be related to the quota plan defined for your org, which specifies maximum values for memory, routes, and services. See [Creating and Modifying Quota Plans](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/quota-plans.html) in the Cloud Foundry docs for more information.